# Correct approach (in autolayout) to resize superview and re-layout subviews?

Tags: ios, xcode5, autolayout

I'm trying to make sense of an autolayout issue. I have a small custom view that itself has an imageView and a couple of labels. The image is fetched from a server and includes some metadata to help the app determine where the text should be placed. For now, I just need to limit the width of the labels (triggering word wrap) to avoid putting text over top of a logo in the background.

To make this easier, I thought I could create a containing view for the two labels. That way, I could resize the container and (I thought) the sub-views would follow suit.

[image: Screenshot from Xcode]

I'm pretty sure I have the constraints set up correctly, because it all works OK until I start fiddling with the frame:

[image: Image before fiddling]

When the image is fetched from the server, I resize the frame as follows:

```
CGRect frame = self.labelContainerView.frame;
frame.size.width = my_limited_width;
self.labelContainerView.frame = frame;
```

And I can see that the container itself has been resized, but its child views haven't:

[image: Resized container with un-resized child views]

To try to trigger the layout, I've done:

```
[self.labelContainerView setNeedsLayout];
[self.labelContainerView layoutIfNeeded];
```

... but this ends up just restoring the original constraints from the .xib. That's a handy feature and all... and it's one that I might need... but not what I need here.

I've seen posts that hint that resizing frames is the wrong thing to do here; that you should get a handle on the appropriate constraint and fiddle with it instead. I tried that:

```
self.rightMarginConstraint.constant = 150;
```

... and it almost works:

[image: Adjusted constraint on right edge of superview]

But in this case, that first (larger) label never grows beyond two lines, even if its height constraint is set to be <= something ridiculously huge. The layout system isn't re-computing how many lines the label will need.

Obviously I don't understand enough about the way views, frames, and autolayout work together to be able to see the solution for myself, which is why I'm asking here. What's the correct way to solve this problem?

Comment: Setting the frame is definitely not the way to go if you are using autolayout. Your second approach is correct. Regarding the label height problem... it may have to do with the "Bottom space to label: subtitle" constraint. Does the subtitle label has a bottom space constraint to the parent view? also, what do you want to happen when the first label is to big? simple move down the subtitle? hide it?

Comment: You need to change the height of the container to make space if you reduce the width. What do you have that does that?

Comment: @Matías R: Simply move the subtitle down. There's no bottom space constraint on the subtitle label.

Comment: The simply set number of lines to 0 and remove the height constraint (both) in the first label

Comment: Did you modify the values of Content hugging/resistance priority? That might be the cause. Anyway, should I post it as an answer?

Comment: Sorry @MatiasR, I spoke too soon. That didn't work. Been trying too many things here. If the initial autolayout gives my label 2 lines, I don't ever get any more than 2 lines when I change the constraint constant. Label's lines are already set to zero. I didn't change the content hugging/resistance at all.

Comment: Alright, a few more things to try. Call `[self.labelContainerView updateConstraints];` instead of needsLayout/layoutIfNeeded. This should be done below the line `self.rightMarginConstraint.constant = 150;`

Comment: Looks like I'm not supposed to call updateConstraints directly, but setNeedsUpdateConstraints+updateConstraintsIfNeeded. But in any case, that didn't do it either. This gets back to my original question: How do I trigger a complete re-layout, as if we were starting from scratch? Is that even possible?

Comment: That should do it. Can you post a screenshot of the constraints of the subtitle label?

Comment: There are only 3 constraints on the subtitle, they're essentially the same as the title: top space to nearest neighbor, leading to container, trailing to container. In playing a little more, it seems like it may need a bottom constraint somewhere to make the right decision. You've been very helpful; if you want to post your first comment as an answer I'll gladly accept it. Then maybe we can clean up this comment-a-thon here.

Comment: I think this might be the bug that I'm up against. See the last comment on this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22046350/autolayout-preventing-3-line-label-from-having-more-than-two-lines

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @MatíasR noted in the comments, the proper way to do this is to manipulate the constraint rather than setting the frame directly.

I submitted this to Apple Developer Technical Support (DTS) and received the answer to the second part of my question. When the layout occurs, the labels need to have their preferredMaxLayoutWidth updated:

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
{
    self.titleLabel.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = self.titleLabel.bounds.size.width;
    self.subtitleLabel.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = self.subtitleLabel.bounds.size.width;
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];
}
```

I still had to force a new layout, but that was easy:

```
self.rightMarginConstraint.constant = 150;
[self.labelContainerView setNeedsLayout];
[self.labelContainerView layoutIfNeeded];
```

Thanks to @MatíasR for helping eliminate a variable. Once I knew the correct approach, I was able to submit a very specific chunk of sample code to DTS.